# Importing multiple excel files and combining into dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to import many excel files (around 400) into one dataframe from a folder but I seem to be running into an error.

The files I want from my folder are names filename followed by a date - "filename_yyyy_mm_dd.xlsx".

I want to keep the header as the files have all same columns for different dates.

My current code is:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os


path = r"C:\Users\..."

my_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "filename*.xlsx"))

file_li = []

for filename in my_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=1)
    file_li.append(df)
    
frame = pd.concat(file_li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

When I call my frame I dont get any response? Am I doing something wrong in the way I am calling the file name?

Update:

My excel files look like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 | Column 7 | Column 8 | Column 9 | Column 10 | Column 11 | Column 12 | Column 13 | Column 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date | SREC-MD | SREC | Feb-25 | MDX | F |  | 85 | 0 | 0 | 8086 | 02/25/2025 | 20107 |  |

with around 300-400 rows.

My output has captured the 14 columns but it has added a lot more as doing frame.info() shows I have 922 columns.

Update 2:

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: _When I call my frame I dont get any response?_ What do you mean by that ?

Comment: At first it didn't run but now it runs with an incorrect output...it has appended extra numeric columns  that doesnt exist in the file

Comment: Can you show how look like your input (one of the Excel files) and the (incorrect) output ?

Comment: Added onto original post, thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my machine with your code. Can you check if your spreadsheets do not contain hidden columns ? Also it may be better if you add a screenshot of the incorrect output.

Comment: sure - I have added. The excel sheets do not have hidden columns but I realized it does not start from row 1 in the excel but rather row 2. It has same number of columns, however. Hence I do not know, why my df has 922 columns with the above code.

Comment: Can you set `header=None` ? _(this will not give you the final expected result but just to make sure if the extra columns will disappear)_

Comment: Yes! That's worked. Now I think I need to solve it for moving row two to become the column header.

Comment: Nice and don't forget, *row 2 in Excel* is equivalent to `header=1` in pandas. So make sure that all the Excel files, worksheets has a header starting at row 2 in Excel and then set `header=1`.

Comment: I initially had that and that is when I ended up with 922 rows. Only none gets the correct number of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell why you're getting the extra columns but you can try this :

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os


path = r"C:\Users\..."

my_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "filename*.xlsx"))

file_li = []

for filename in my_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=None)
    file_li.append(df)
    
frame = (
            pd.concat(file_li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
                .dropna(how="all") #to get rid of the eventual extra rows abobe each header
                .drop_duplicates() #to get rid of the cumulated duplicated headers
                .T.set_index(0).T #to make the first row as header of the dataframe
        )
```

I suggest you however to check if there is any missing rows in `frame` compared to your spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using concat, you could try reading the files into a df and then append them to one combined csv using mode='a'. Then read the combined csv.

```
for filename in my_files:
       df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=1)
       df.to_csv('combined.csv', mode='a', header=False)


df = pd.read_csv('combined.csv')
```